# Soft starter design Using Back to Back SCRs three phase induction motor

Tags: power-electronics, three-phase, induction-motor

I am seeking a help to design the firing angle technic of my Squirrel Cage Induction Motor Soft Starter of Back to Back SCRs. How to calculate the appropriate firing angle? and what are the wave forms required for each pulse from the firing angle?

Answer (score 0):

From the way you worded your question, it appears you are totally unfamiliar with phase angle firing techniques for SCRs I don't think this is the place to try to learn complex concepts like that. If you are designing your own Soft Starter, good luck, there are lots of them on the market already and the market is shrinking. If you are just curious and want to try it yourself, you need to start at the very beginning of what SCRs are, how you fire them, then how that applies to 3 phase circuits and lastly, how that applies to motors. That took me about 4 years to learn, lots of mistakes along the way...

Comment: Thank you for your comment... It is true that I have not managed to express my point correctly. I know what SCRs are and I know how they can be fired.. But my question really was how the apply them to motors. and what is the best firing angle for for each SCR